# Typo3 7.6 - Disable absRefPrefix only in HMENU, not on complete site

Tags: typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Im using a multidomain Typo3 installation with an absolute absRefPrefix path in my Typoscript. No I want to include the hreflang for Google. Its working so far, but I need to change the domain url for special languages.

This is what works for translating the links, but without changing the main url:

```
page.headerData.22 = HMENU
page.headerData.22 {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,2,8
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
      stdWrap.cObject {
        value = en || de || tr || it
      }
      linkWrap = <link rel="alternate" hreflang="|
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      after.cObject = TEXT
      after.cObject {
        stdWrap.wrap = " href="|" />
        stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = page:uid
        stdWrap.typolink.additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=2 || &L=8 || &L=7
        stdWrap.typolink.returnLast = url
        stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString = 1
        stdWrap.typolink.addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
      }
    }
    CUR = 1
    CUR {
      doNotShowLink = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who has the same Problem.
For me I found the following solution:

I create the hreflang HMENU

```
temp.hreflangValue = HMENU
```

Then I make an replacement for the baseURL

```
temp.hreflangValue {
stdWrap.replacement {
10 {
  search = myBaseURL
  replace = myNewOrOtherBaseUrl
}
}
}
```

And put it into page.headerData

```
page.headerData.40 < temp.hreflangValue
```